# Static route - gateway not used

Tags: routing, static-routes, ip-forwarding

I'm trying to use gateway address `10.10.121.10` in order to forward TCP traffic via this machine. I would like to make that traffic from my machine is going over `10.10.121.10` and that machine `10.200.32.107` thinks it is coming from `10.10.121.10` and not my machine. It seems that whatever I set in windows - it doesn't care about set Gateway address.

Here is the status without static route set:

[image]

This is what I would expect - no route set to `10.200.32.107` and I cannot reach that IP.

But when I add this static route as here

[image]

Destination is reachable, but not via `10.10.121.10`. It seems that this `Gateway` address does not matter here - even if I put here random IP (eg I tried with `1.1.1.1`) it will work.

What I expected is that traffic is directed as in green steps on image:

1. I want to reach `10.200.32.107`, so use route for `10.200.32.0 255.255.255.0`
2. Gateway is `10.10.121.10`, so use route for `10.10.121.10 255.255.255.255`
3. Gateway is `192.168.24.1` so go there and forward traffic to `10.10.121.10` on TAP-Windows Adapter V9 (VPN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, What I end up doing in the end is to install `pptpd` on raspberry and configure it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
sudo nano /etc/pptpd.conf
```

and add at the bottom

```
localip 199.168.0.1
remoteip 199.168.0.234-238,199.168.0.245
```

Then I just added rules to `iptables`

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sun Nov  1 21:00:46 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3303:295008]
:INPUT ACCEPT [434:44479]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [51:3332]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Nov  1 21:00:46 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sun Nov  1 21:00:46 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [6349:640268]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3318:257937]
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Nov  1 21:00:46 2020
```

And on windows I installed new network:

[image]

And then, since I'm using OpenConnect, I edited the file `vpnc-script.js` in order to automate connecting to `piVNP` - I just added

```
echo("Connecting to piVPN...");
exec("rasdial \"piVPN\" \"default\" \"default\"");
echo("Adding my static route...");
exec("route add 10.200.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 199.168.0.1 metric 36");
```

In connect method, and then in disconnect just added:

```
echo("Disconnecting from piVPN...");
exec("rasdial \"piVPN\" /disconnect");
```

Now everything is automated and working perfectly...

Comment: and just to mention that I had to do `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1000`, otherwise connection kept dropping after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to manage how routing will happen behind the router you are connected to. There is no possible option in the packet you can set to be read on router to change its behavior.

The only thing your computer can decide is what will be the next hop. So, all your routing table is just a way to choose 192.168.24.1 as a next hop and nothing more. 192.168.24.1 will decide what to do next and you can't change its behavior from your computer.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in some different way? I can modify software on `10.10.121.10` - that is - install whatever needed. I guess that installing OpenVPN on `10.10.121.10` would work, but is there any easier solution?

Comment: Depends on what you want. If your problem is 10.200.32.107 "not liking" your address then 10.10.121.10 have to have NAT masquerading address of source host. If traffic is going around 10.10.121.10 - you need to change 192.168.24.1 routing table.

Comment: My problem is `10.200.32.107` "not liking" my address, but addres `10.10.121.10` is OK. I cannot change anything on `192.168.24.1`.

Comment: But how then to easily direct traffic to `10.200.32.107` over `10.10.121.10`?